# Why is the first Query working and the second not? (Spring application JPA)

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I have two Query's that I want to use in a Spring project (using JPA). The first one gets an account and this works correctly. For the second one I want it to be able to update the 'disabled' field in the database. The codes look like this:

```
// This is the first Query (works correctly)
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Account findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);

// This is the second Query (doesn't work)
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE accounts SET disabled = 1 WHERE email= ?1 ", nativeQuery = true)
int disableAccountByEmail(String emailAddress);
```

I did read somewhere I needed to add @Modifying and this will return an int or void. But when I try to test if it works I get a **TransactionRequiredException** error  that says: *Executing an update/delete* query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below for update query

```
 @Transactional
 @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
```